# Android Diamond Button Layout

Tags: android, android-layout, user-interface

I am currently working on a sample application using android studio. I need to design **diamond shaped buttons and view them as follows** (Screenshots attached). But I don't have an idea how to make this kind of thing with android.

---

There are be four diamond shaped buttons, and they are be aligned as according to the following screenshot.

---

### Screenshot:

[image: Android Button Layout]

Comment: instead of using button try imagebutton or imageview

Comment: you can use button with property app:rotation

Comment: thanks, but how to align buttons like that?

Comment: i am trying to do that wait may be can give you some sample

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Here is sample code adjust margins according to devices you can use imageView instead buttons

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
                android:layout_width="match_parent"
                android:layout_height="match_parent">
    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/firstRow"
        android:rotation="-30"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginTop="30dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button 2"
            android:id="@+id/button2" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button 1"
            android:id="@+id/button1"/>
    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/secondRow"
        android:layout_below="@+id/firstRow"
        android:rotation="-30"
        android:layout_marginTop="24dp"
        android:layout_marginLeft="68dp"
        android:orientation="horizontal"
        android:layout_width="wrap_content"
        android:layout_height="wrap_content">
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button 4"
            android:id="@+id/button4" />
        <Button
            android:layout_width="80dp"
            android:layout_height="80dp"
            android:text="Button 3"
            android:id="@+id/button3"/>

    </LinearLayout>

</RelativeLayout>
```

Answer (score 1):

The easiest way is use .png archives on ImageButtons and display them on a RelativeLayout. You can change positions and adjust them as you wish. If you set the `android:background="@android:color/transparent"` you can set your form, by playing with the margins (`android:layout_marginRight=""`, `android:layout_marginTop=""`, etc.)

With that I got this:

[image]

This is the code I used; it's only necessary .xml, without programmatic changes:

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
android:layout_width="match_parent"
android:layout_height="match_parent"
android:background="@android:color/holo_purple"
android:paddingBottom="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin"
android:paddingLeft="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingRight="@dimen/activity_horizontal_margin"
android:paddingTop="@dimen/activity_vertical_margin" >

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignParentRight="true"
    android:layout_alignParentTop="true"
    android:layout_marginRight="39dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/im"
    android:src="@drawable/diamond" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignLeft="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_centerVertical="true"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/im"
    android:src="@drawable/diamond" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_below="@+id/imageButton1"
    android:layout_marginRight="55dp"
    android:layout_marginTop="47dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/im"
    android:src="@drawable/diamond" />

<ImageButton
    android:id="@+id/ImageButton02"
    android:layout_width="wrap_content"
    android:layout_height="wrap_content"
    android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/ImageButton03"
    android:layout_alignRight="@+id/ImageButton04"
    android:layout_marginBottom="66dp"
    android:layout_marginRight="5dp"
    android:background="@android:color/transparent"
    android:contentDescription="@string/im"
    android:src="@drawable/diamond" /></RelativeLayout>
```

Hope it helps.

Answer (score 0):

```
<RelativeLayout xmlns:android="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res/android"
    xmlns:app="http://schemas.android.com/apk/res-auto"
    xmlns:tools="http://schemas.android.com/tools"
    android:layout_width="match_parent"
    android:layout_height="match_parent"
    android:orientation="vertical"
    android:background="@drawable/splash2"
    tools:context="com.example.sv.myfoodapplication.view.SplashActivity">

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_breakfast"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_above="@+id/sp_desert"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sp_vegetable"
        android:layout_marginBottom="43dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_diamond">


    </LinearLayout>

    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_meat"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sp_vegetable"
        android:layout_alignStart="@+id/sp_desert"
        android:layout_marginBottom="80dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_diamond" >

    </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_vegetable"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignBottom="@+id/sp_desert"
        android:layout_alignParentStart="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="83dp"
        android:layout_marginStart="19dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_diamond" >

         </LinearLayout>


    <LinearLayout
        android:id="@+id/sp_desert"
        android:layout_width="200dp"
        android:layout_height="200dp"
        android:layout_alignParentBottom="true"
        android:layout_centerHorizontal="true"
        android:layout_marginBottom="10dp"
        android:orientation="vertical"
        android:gravity="center"
        android:background="@drawable/shape_diamond">

    </LinearLayout>


</RelativeLayout>
```

Comment: Welcome to Stack Overflow. Firstly, does this question really need another answer? There are already several similar answers provided plus your answer contains no explanation that explains how it works or why I should use it instead of the other answers. [How to Answer](https://stackoverflow.com/help/how-to-answer) Lastly, this is being answered using RelativeLayout which is now classified as a 'legacy' layout. Answering this using ConstraintLayout, the 2018 way of doing things, and offering an explanation could add more value...